# Azure cloud remote Debugger attach : error specified method is not supported

Tags: azure, remote-debugging

I have enabled the debugging for **Visual studio 2017** in **App Service** and save the settings.
I also have opened the port **4022, 4023 and 3702**
but when I try to attach debugger through Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio 2017 to the App Service I am getting below error:

**cloud explorer has encountered an unexpected error:
 the requested action could not be completed. Detail: specified method is not supported**
[image]

Could any body please help me solve this issue

Comment: Check if you enable debug for your Web App in Azure portal: Go to Azure portal > Your Web App > Application settings > Debugging, It should be On and choose the right version for your Visual studio.

Comment: I already done this setup both visual studio and debugging option checked are 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking that the Portals are opened 4022, 4023 and 3702 and Debug settings is enabled for Visual studio 2017 in APP Service, company's network was not opened for the range of the IP address for the West Europe data center of Azure and also company Network had VPN network enabled to Azure Subscription which did not allowed to debug in an other subscription and failed to attached debugger.
I put together all the check points in detail at [here](https://scientistz.com/2018/01/solved-the-visual-studio-2017-remote-debugger-msvsmon-exe-does-not-appear-to-be-running-on-the-remote-computer-this-may-be-because-a-firewall-is-preventing-communication-to-the-remote-computer/)

I hope this would help any one who encountered this specific error.

Comment: If you need immediate debugging needs then you also have option to create a VM in Azure, not on premises and use this VM to attach debugger and start debugging until the network issue is resolved by your Organization.